# My Vs pygame still don't show highlight after I fix the no module of INIT AND QUIT

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am new to python, `pygame`. After I fix my `pygame` no module of `INIT` and `QUIT` as the answer adding

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [         "--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame"     ]
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]       }
```

but my VS pygame method still don't have the highlight.

Comment: What is the effect of "highlight" you expect? Please check whether the extension '_Python_' in VS Code is installed and available.